# Stopping Thread on Mouse Hover Event in Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, mouseevent, event-dispatch-thread

I have a desktop application in which I am showing one Frame as notification but I want to stop that thread when mouse hover to the notification frame. Then how could I can do that?

Here current code:

```
final Notification not = new Notification();
Notification.notification_name.setText(msg[1]);

final ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
s.schedule(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        not.setVisible(false); //should be invoked on the EDT
        not.dispose();
    }
}, 6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It's showing and Exit in 6 sec.

The code that I am trying.

```
final Notification not = new Notification();
not.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
            super.mouseEntered(e);
            System.out.println("Mouse Entered");
            //s.wait();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
            super.mouseExited(e);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});


final ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
s.schedule(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        not.setVisible(false); //should be invoked on the EDT
        not.dispose();
    }
}, 6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In this code Notification frame is showing till 6 sec but if user hover that frame then it should be Show till user mouse exit from that Frame.

Comment: Use a `javax.swing.Timer`. Don't modify the state of UI components from outside the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have to show that Frame till that Mouse Exit from that Frame. how can i use that?

Comment: `javax.swing.Timer` has `stop` and `restart` methods

Comment: but if i start that timer then will it be let to execute next thread along with that.?

Comment: The timer will wait in it's own thread and will provide notification of the time-out in the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer okey bro m trying that:)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Notification is already shown but it will be dispose in 6 sec but if user hover that notification then i want to show that till user removes mouse hover from that. :(

Comment: Yep, start the timer when the notification is shown or on `mouseExited`, stop the timer on `mouseEntered`

Comment: @MadProgrammer look i have edited code what is current code and what i am trying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you deal with anything that might affect the UI in some way, you need to be careful and ensure that everything is done within the context of the EDT.

`javax.swing.Timer` allows you to setup a callback at some time in the future that when triggered, will be called within the context of the EDT

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TimeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimeExample();
    }

    public TimeExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

            timer = new Timer(6000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);

            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();
                        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.restart();
                        setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background"));
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Testing purposes only!!
                 *
                 * @param e
                 */
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background"));
                    timer.restart();
                }

            };
            addMouseListener(ma);

            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

    }

}
```

Have a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: I almost there.. :D ;)

Comment: `mail.add(cheque)` ;)

Comment: Hahaha sure one day ;) and ya t.start(); will start from first na. if i want to resume that timer then how to do that?

Comment: Yes, `start` should `reset` the timer back to an initial value

Comment: and when i tried to call it again its now showing Notification :(

Comment: i mean its showing only once and when i hover it still its dispose :(

Comment: I would need to see an example to be able to say more

Comment: its done :) and ya i was using frame so it was not accepting till i have other frame open